# How to convert QPixmap into a Matrix

Tags: qt, matrix, transform, qpixmap

I have been looking for such answers.

I found this method in QPixmap *transformed()* though I think it does not help me in my pursuit of searching a method to convert QPixmap Images (grayscale) into a Matrix...

Thanks for the help =)

Comment: What do you mean by Matrix? There is no such class in Qt or in standard C++ AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry: I refer this Matrix as a multi-dimentional array that can be used for statistical purposes (like biometrics, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The `QMatrix` in the `QPixmap::transformed()` function is specifically for warping images.

I think what you want to do is read the values from a `QPixmap` into some matrix.
You don't specify what grayscale means but I presume that `qGray(QRgb)` is sufficient if the image is not already grayscale.

I think basically something like this is what you need:

```
QImage myimage = mypixmap.toImage();    // convert your QPixmap to QImage
int width = myimage.width();
int height = myimage.height();
int *matrix = new int [width*height];   // store 2-D data in 1-D vector

for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
    matrix[j*width+i] = qGray(myimage.pixel(i,j));
  }
}

// ... do stuff ...

delete [] matrix;
```

You can easily change the matrix variable into some other layout in memory if you like.

Comment: I like your answer which is elegant. I'm going to use it for the reverse operation : QImage creation from a matrix (QVector<QRgb>)